# CSS anchor text-align its content center not working

Tags: css, anchor, text-align

Try to align the div in the center of the link, not working. still align left.

```css
a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <div>
    Hello World
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `margin` to `auto` on the div and remove the `text-align` rule on the anchor:

```css
a {
  display: block;
  background: green;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <div>
    Hello World
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: why margin is needed?

Comment: @eastwater By setting a width on your div, and specifying the margin as auto, it's split equally and centers the div

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block;` on the `div` to allow that:

```css
a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <div>
    Hello World
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set div style **Margin 0 auto**

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <div>
    Hello World
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways in which this can be achieved; the following code snippet shows a few of those approaches with explanatory comments:

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em;
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  width: clamp(10em, 70vw, 1000px);
}

/* styling all <a> elements: */
a {
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  padding-block: 0.25em;
}

/* styling all <div> elements: */
div {
  border: 1px solid palegreen;
  text-align: start;
}

/* using the ::before pseudo-element to
   show the 'Hello World string: */
div::before {
  content: "Hello World";
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

/* styling all <code> elements: */
code {
  /* display: block purely to allow for
     padding to be applied on the inline
     axis: */
  display: block;
  /* to show the code as it was written,
     including line-breaks: */
  white-space: pre;
  padding-inline: 1em 0.5em;
}

a.withMarginInline div {
  /* using the margin-inline of 'auto' to move the <div>
     to the center of its parent: */
  margin-inline: auto;
  /* setting the width of the <div> to a width which fits its
     content, allowing lines to wrap as needed: */
  width: fit-content;
}

/* retaining the 'text-align' property of 'center': */
a.withDisplayInlineBlock {
  text-align: center;
}

/* displaying the <div> as an inline-block, which allows it
   to be positioned as an inline element, but also allows it
   to have specified width, height, margin...: */
a.withDisplayInlineBlock div {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* setting the <a> parent to flex-box layout: */
a.withDisplayFlex {
  display: flex;
  /* centering the content of that element (horizontally),
     if vertical centering is required then
     'align-content: center' could be added, or
     'place-content: center' used in place of both: */
  justify-content: center;
}

a.withDisplayGrid {
  /* using grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* positioning the content vertically and horizontally
     in the centre: */
  place-content: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <a href="#" class="withMarginInline">
    <div>
      <code>
childElement {
  margin-inline: auto;
  width: fit-content;
}
      </code>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="withDisplayInlineBlock">
    <div>
      <code>
parentElement {
  text-align: center;
}

childElement {
  display: inline-block;
}
      </code>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="withDisplayFlex">
    <div>
      <code>
parentElement {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
      </code>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="withDisplayGrid">
    <div>
      <code>
parentElement {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}
      </code>
    </div>
  </a>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pbuyqj15/).

References:

- [`align-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content/).
- [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).
- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`clamp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp).
- [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`margin-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block).
- [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline).
- [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
- [`padding-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block).
- [`padding-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block).
- [`place-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-content).
- [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).
- [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).
- [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width).